# Mac OS X never shuts down

Tags: macos, shutdown, kernel-extensions

When trying to shutdown or restart my Mac it just keep on showing the spinning wheel with the white background. I have waited for at least 15 minutes but nothing happens.

When safe booting I can successfully shutdown OS X so I guess it is probably caused by a kernel extension.

How can I find out what is hanging the shutdown process?

---

Result of doing `kextstat -kl | awk ' !/apple/ { print $6 } '`:

```
com.rogueamoeba.InstantOn
com.globaldelight.driver.BoomDevice
com.intel.kext.intelhaxm
com.rogueamoeba.InstantOnCore
com.Cycling74.driver.Soundflower
org.pqrs.driver.KeyRemap4MacBook
foo.tun
foo.tap
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp
```

Comment: @Buscar웃 how do I "use the wake reason"? I don't understand what you mean. Yes I'm using Parallels.

Comment: @Buscar웃 Nope. I have removed it from the menubar.

Comment: ok, you can go true the shutdown logs and see who is making problems, also look in the /private/var/log/shutdown_monitor.log (it should be empty)

Comment: The spotlight was the problem yesterday, not today.

Comment: This is the file I am looking at launchd-shutdown.Tyilo.log you started the shutdown on Job manager shutdown begun at: Fri Sep 20 07:46:02 2013

Comment: OK, your problem starts here 1211934  com.apple.launchd.peruser.501  249      com.apple.imagent 270  Job was sent SIGTERM.  There is no clean shutdown after that.

Comment: Try starting up in [verbose mode](https://support.apple.com/kb/ht1492) -- as far as I remember, this prints diagnostic information on shutdown as well as boot.

Answer (score 1):

Does it also happen when you log out? Did you already check `system.log`?

Is there a logout hook (`sudo defaults read com.apple.loginwindow LogoutHook`)? I guess not though, because normally when a logout hook does not terminate, there is a solid light gray screen without any process indicator.

You could try unloading the kernel extensions with `sudo kextunload -b $bundleid` before restarting. Or just move the kext bundles outside `/System/Library/Extensions/` and restart once so the kernel extensions won't be loaded.

You could also try terminating different processes before logging out, or for example run `for f in {~,}/Library/Launch{Agents,Daemons}/*.plist; do launchctl unload $f; done`.