# iMac restarts instead of shutting down

Tags: startup, shutdown, nvram

I have a problem with my iMac restarting when it should be shutting down. This doesn't happen all the time but appears to happen more frequently when I've had the computer on for a few hours.

**What happens**

1. I shut the computer down via Apple Menu > Shut Down
2. The shut down cycle completes
3. The computer immediately reboots

It doesn't behave like this [Mac OS X never shuts down](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/102486/mac-os-x-never-shuts-down). The Mac responds to being shut down immediately.

**Fixes I've tried**

First I should state I've pulled out all USBs etc. The only wire in is the power cable.

*Disk Utility*

I've been in touch with Apple Support about this issue, and the only advice they could give was to run First Aid in the Disk Utility. Sometimes this allows me to shut down. Other times not.

*Resetting the SMC*

I've reset the SMC which doesn't help. This often leads to another issue which is freezing on reboot (Apple logo and progress bar that doesn't move). To fix this I reset the PRAM/VRAM

*Reset the PRAM/VRAM*

Resetting the PRAM allows me to shut down most of the time. Even then I have to do it 2 or 3 times before it works.

*Complete reinstall/upgrade*

I've also reinstalled the system twice, one time upgrading from El Capitan to Sierra. This has temporarily fixed the issue, but it soon comes back after a week or so.

**Setup**

iMac (27-inch, Late 2013)

3.4 GHz Intel Core i5

6 GB 1600 MHz DDR3

NVIDIA GeForce GTX 775M 2048 MB

macOS Sierra 10.12.5

**EDIT:** Current Energy Saver Settings

[image: Energy Saver Settings]

I'd really appreciate your help here guys, this has been going on a while and it's becoming a bit of a nuisance.

**EDIT:** This question appears to highlight a pretty common occurrence. I'm happy to invest more into the bounty to get an answer that resolves or at least identifies the problem causing it to happen.

**UPDATE:**

After going through the steps in the answer provided by @monomeeth, Apple Diagnostics uncovered an error `NDT001: There may be an issue with the Thunderbolt hardware`. I've run Diagnostics before, but this time I ran it straight after the Mac restarted from a failed shut down. I'll be taking it into Apple for repair, so I'll keep this answer up to date with the outcome.

Comment: I'm also interested as I know of a macbook (roughly 2009 ish) that does just about exactly the same but all the time - shut down : instant reboot... Tried smc, pram, complete reinstall etc so if anyone has any leads I would be pleased as well. Oh, not complaining I have 4 other macs in the house which are fine !

Comment: In Terminal, type the command `sudo poweroff` when you want to shut down - does it still exhibit the same behavior?

Comment: Also, in *Sys Prefs -> Energy Saver -> Power* make sure the box *Start Up Automatically After Power Failure* is unchecked.

Comment: Thx @Allan. Have posted current Energy Saver settings above. Will try `sudo poweroff` at next opportunity.

Comment: Maybe try [Apple Diagnostics](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT202731) to see if it’s a hardware issue

Comment: What's the content of your Boot.plist? (`cat /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.Boot.plist`) < there is a space between *cat* and */Lib...*!

Comment: And? What was the issue? I'm haveing some very similar situation.

Comment: @LucasRaphaelPianegonda I never got to the bottom of it. I'm still using the same iMac right now in the same condition. There has been a crackling coming from the back for a while now, so I'm convinced that this could actually be an issue with the power supply.

Comment: @mrbubbles Which means that the mac is doing it for 2 years now and it is still fine? No other issues?

Comment: @LucasRaphaelPianegonda That's right. Just the annoying crackle. I don't leave it plugged in overnight either haha.

Answer (score 4):

Troubleshooting is a process of elimination and you seem to have started off well, doing most of the obvious first steps. Below are some additional steps I'd try next, especially since reinstalling macOS only resolved the problem for a week or so.

**Test your iMac in Safe Mode**

Follow these steps to boot your iMac into Safe Mode:

1. Fully shut down your iMac
2. Restart your iMac
3. Immediately press the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key and **keep it down**
4. Let go of the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key when you see the login window (NOTE: If you have FileVault enabled you may need to log in twice).
5. Take a note of what happens (i.e. can you shut down normally or is the issue still present)
6. Exit Safe Mode by restarting your iMac as normal
7. Now test again after the reboot

Now, depending on the above testing, we can narrow down how to proceed:

- If the problem **is** still present *during* Safe Mode and afterwards, proceed to **1. Run Apple Diagnostics** (see below).
- If the problem **is not** present during Safe Mode then it's time to investigate login items, fonts, and kernel extensions. If that's the case, proceed to **2. Investigating login items, fonts, and kernel extensions** (see below).

---

**1. Run Apple Diagnostics**

Follow the steps below to run Apple Diagnostics:

1. Fully shut down your iMac
2. Restart your iMac
3. Immediately press the <kbd>D</kbd> key and **keep it down** until you see the Diagnostics screen appear
4. Wait for Diagnostics to finish (this typically only takes a few minutes)
5. Once complete, one of two things will appear on the screen:

   - a *No issues found* message
   - a brief description of any errors found plus further instructions
6. If the diagnostics test does find errors, take a note of what they are

**Note:** If pressing and holding the <kbd>D</kbd> key at Step 3 doesn't work, start again at Step 1 and, at Step 3 press and hold both the <kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> keys instead. This will try and run diagnostics from the internet instead, so you will need to allow more time for it to complete.

---

**2. Investigating login items, fonts, and kernel extensions**

Let's start with Login Items:

1. Startup normally
2. Go to System Preferences > Users & Groups
3. Select the Login Items tab
4. Take a note of your Login Items
5. Now remove all of them by highlighting them and clicking on the <kbd>-</kbd> button below
6. Restart your computer

Now your Mac will boot up without those login items loading. Test this and see if the problem persists:

- If the problem goes away you know one (or more) of the Login items were causing the problem. You can then add them back in one by one until you've identified the culprit. Problem solved.
- If the problem does persist, it's either a problem with fonts you've installed yourself or with a 3rd party kernel extension. A little more info below:

**Fonts:-** You can remove any of the fonts you've installed yourself to see if this makes a difference.

**Kernel Extensions:-** You can open Terminal (found within your Utilites folder) and enter the following command:

`kextstat | grep -v com.apple`

The above command will list 3rd party kernel extensions (you may need to stretch the Terminal window so it's easier to read). Look for anything you don't remember installing, or something that belongs to software you've removed, or just anything that looks out of place. Remember though, this is a list of **3rd party kernel extensions** and therefore any of them could be causing the problem.

Comment: Thanks @Monomeeth. There are definitely some things in your answer I haven't tried yet. Will let you know the outcome.

Comment: Running through your answer brought something up @Monomeeth. Have updated the answer above.

Comment: Ah yes, that could explain it. One thing though, if you happen to have any Thunderbolt devices connected, it'd be worth running Apple Diagnostics again without them attached to eliminate the possibility of a false positive due to an external cable/device. However, going to Apple is certainly a good course of action. And thanks for keeping us all updated, as this may help other users in future too. :)

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue. My iMac 2019 21.5 restarts when i shut down it. The problem is in onboard battery BR1632A. Battery has 1,6V when it installed in socket.But this battery must have 3V. Replacing whith a new battery solved this

Answer (score 0):

I have been troubleshooting this very issue for weeks here is the information I have found so far.

1. When you need to shutdown you computer completely select apple restart and then press and hold the power button while it's restarting so it doesn't turn back on. This bypasses the bug that puts your computer in a restart loop on shutdown.

In any of the troubleshooting steps that involve shutting down your computer do this instead.

When the mac ends up in a restart loop it's called Kernel Panic.

1. With almost all technical problems you should start by resetting the NVRAM, and PRAM. https://www.macworld.com/article/224955/how-to-reset-a-macs-nvram-pram-and-smc.html
2. You can also boot your machine in recovery mode and scan your disks for errors. https://www.macworld.com/article/350806/macos-disk-utility-how-to-verify-storage.html
3. Run apple diagnostics on your mac: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202731
4. Open System Settings/Users & Groups and Eliminate unneeded applications that are running on startup.
5. Use the Mac activity monitory to see if any applications are taking up a large amount of resources.

If none of the above fixes the issues you have to start looking at workarounds.

1. Update the power savings settings on your computer.
   These settings will appear under either System Settings/Battery or System.
2. If you are on a desktop computer you should see a setting to 
   "Startup automatically after a power failure"

    Please check this option if present.
3. On laptops you should see the following settings:

- Turn display off after _ time
- Prevent your mac from automatically sleeping when display is off.

  If the reboot loop on your machine is triggered when the OS attempts to force your computer to sleep setting it so it never does that will prevent the issue.

Many people have had to reinstall their operating system and wipe out all their personal data to fix this issue so if you aren't keeping regular backups yet start doing so. Apple TimeMachine makes it easy to do.